# Primefaces: How to change layout toggler position

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to place the North Layout toggler from the left to the right side of the screen (when colapsed).

I've tried both

```
.ui-layout-toggler-north {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px !important;
}
```

and

```
.ui-layout-toggler {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px !important;
}
```

but it's not working. 
The !important is not overriding the original div format and the "left: 0px" in the original code is the active format.

```
<div id="j_idt8-toggler" class="ui-layout-toggler ui-layout-toggler-north ui-layout-toggler-closed ui-layout-toggler-north-closed" title="Open" style="position: absolute; ... height: 25px; **left: 0px;** top: 0px;">
```

Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. The tags just have to be overridden with the 'left' tag, something like this:

```
.ui-layout-toggler-north, .ui-layout-toggler-south{
    position: absolute;
    left: 97% !important;
}
```